# Can we share an application level cache between multiple Kafka Streams tasks

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I have an in memory cache in a Kafka Streams application. the input topic has 2 partitions so for maximum parallelism I configure 1 streams application instance with 2 threads.

Within my stream processor, I make remote call to fetch some data and put it in a Map to cache it.

Since Kafka streams will assign 1 thread to each task and both tasks will try to update the cached map in parallel, do I have to take care of making the cached map thread safe? Is it not advisable to share an application level cache in an application instance that could be running multiple Kafka streams tasks?

Comment: Do both threads need access to the same data in the cache? Or, does each thread need to cache the data it is interested in?

Comment: both need access to same data.

Comment: If you have multiple threads, you would need to make the cache thread safe. -- In general, the cache could become the bottleneck, but I guess as long as you are staying with a low number of threads, it might be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for, is a GlobalKTable, which stores data from all the partitions. The way I see it is, you would need to make that remote call, push the result into a topic and then use that topic to create a GlobalKTable within the same app. GlobalKTable is backed by a RocksDB instance which stores data in your "local" file system, and can be queried using the key, much like how you would query a Map.

Word of caution: GlobalKTable source topics can get really huge and might impact your startup times if you aren't using a persistent file system, since the GlobalKTable needs to be hydrated with all the data on the "source" topic (this is done by GlobalStreamThread) before the app actually starts. So, you might want to configure compaction on the "source" topic.

Comment: I think it’s a valid suggestion and I have looked into it. However, the cached data us not owned by my service and also a Kafka topic/global table seems like an overkill for this. I simply want to understand if accessing app level cache will be a problem.